# Rails after create not functioning as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `Case` model (case.rb) I have a few `after_create` callbacks.  One of which is not functioning as expected.

By that I mean when I run it in the console, it works, but when creating it in the controller via an HTTP request, it does not.

Model code (the problem is with `:create_case_users` not working):

```
after_create -> { redis_check(true) },
                         :create_case_users,
                         :create_manager,
                         :pusher_trigger
```

And the `create_case_users` method:

```
def create_case_users
    cus = CaseUser.where(:case_id => self.id, :is_age => 1)

    cus.each do |cu|
        connections = Connection.where({ :cases => 1, :con_id => cu.user_id })

        connections.each do |connection|
            if connection.user_id && connection.connection_id
                case_user = CaseUser.new

                case_user.case_id = self.id
                case_user.user_id = connection.user_id
                case_user.email = connection.cases_emails
                case_user.is_age = 0
                case_user.cm = 0

                case_user.save!
            end
        end
    end
end
```

When running the above snippet in the console of my app, specifying the `Case` to run it for, it works & creates the records I expect.

When I POST to /api/v1/cases, it hits this controller action:

```
@case = Case.new(case_params)
@case.current_user(@current_user)

if @case.save
    render :json => @case, 
                 :root => "case",
                 :status => :created,
                 :location => @case,
                 :serializer => CaseShowSerializer,
                 :current => @current_user
else
    render :json => @case.errors, 
                 :status => :unprocessable_entity
end
```

What could be the problem?  The after create callback after create_case_users runs and functions as expected, meaning `create_case_users` isn't returning false.

Edit:

When running `Case.find(500).create_case_users` in the console it works.

Comment: How are the users you're attempting to retrieve in `cus = CaseUser.where(:case_id => self.id, :is_age => 1)` being created?

Comment: I've verified the AR query works.  It returns one record.

Comment: Ok, let me try once more. You have just created a brand new `Case` here, it will be assigned a brand new auto-generated `id`, and yet in your `create_case_users` method you're selecting the `CaseUser`s that have their `case_id`s set to that `id` - an `id` that has only just been created for the first time in your DB.  So, again, how are those users being created?

Comment: @smathy they're set via the POST request to the controller in JSON ex: `"case_users_attributes": [{}]`

Comment: An array of objects, in this case only one object in the array.

Comment: Ok, so far all you've said is that "it does not [work]" when coming in via the controller. Perhaps you need to expand on that, you said (in a comment on a now deleted answer) that your method does return `cus` when triggered from the controller action? So you must have stepped through that code in a debugger, or put debug log statements in there - so what else in your method is working? Is it finding the `connections`? Does the connection have a `user_id` and a `connection_id`? What exactly did you mean by "it does not work"?